# How to do validations using knockout js validations?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I want to do client side validations using knockout js.

for example , I want to validate below element as required, number only and it should not exceed 10 digits? How can we achieve this using knockout js validation ?

```
<input data-bind='value: phone' required digits='true' maxlength='10' />
```

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Knockout.validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) and use this obsevable extension :

```
phoneNumber.extend({digit: true}).extend({ maxLength: 10 });
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QdQ7B/)

I hope it hepls.

Comment: FYI you don't need to explicitly define the validations in JS if you have the HTML5 attributes on the element AND you set `parseInputAttributes` to true as described [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration)