# what would be the professional way to get noticed if any field is empty

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am make a model using knockout and it have many fields , like

```
function model(){
 var self = this;
 self.field1 = ko.observable('');
 self.field2 = ko.observable('');
 self.field3 = ko.observable('');
 self.field4 = ko.observable('');
 self.field5 = ko.observable('');         
 self.validatemode = function (){

     if(!(self.field1 && self.field2 &&self.field3 &&self.field4 &&self.field5))         
          //Model is not valid 
     }
     else{
       // Model is valid 
    }
 }
```

So this is what i am currently doing but it even doesn't look good to me .

My question is that what would be the more professional way to do this thing .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you checked out [knockout-validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) yet?

Comment: @jeroen No , whats that ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974482/how-to-do-validations-using-knockout-js-validations
and http://jsfiddle.net/QdQ7B/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can put fields in an array, you will check them as following

```
var nonEmpty = false;    
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.fields, function(field){nonEmpty = nonEmpty || field()});
```

Answer (score 0):

knockout validation works but not as good or as easily as jquery validation. Knockout validation is nice because you do not need a form element to validate against but knockout validation is harder because you have to write custom validation to detect if the field is not visible to not validate that field. Jquery is nice because it will do these sorts of things out of the box and you do not have to provide any configuration in your setup besides a form.valid() function.